# ffmpeg copy attached fonts to be used by .ass subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, matroska

I have a .ass file that I want to mux into a video that requires additional fonts.

There seems to be no option to copy the attachments from one file to another, so I dumped them all using

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i input.mkv
```

But how do I get them into the new file correctly?

I have tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -attach "fontastique.ttf" -metadata:s: mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -attach "Franchise - Extra.ttf" -metadata:s: mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -attach "Painfresco-Italic.ttf" -metadata:s: mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -attach "Painfresco-Regular.ttf" -metadata:s: mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -attach "SETFIRETOTHERAIN.TTF" -metadata:s: mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -attach "Volter__28Goldfish.ttf" -metadata:s: mimetype=application/x-truetype-font output.mkv
```

the fonts seem to be attached, but all streams, including video/audio/subtitles, will then show up with a set mimetype of the fonts.

```
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default) (forced)
Metadata:
  MIMETYPE        : application/x-truetype-font
Stream #0:2: Subtitle: ssa (default) (forced)
Metadata:
  MIMETYPE        : application/x-truetype-font
Codec 0x18000 is not in the full list.
Stream #0:3: Attachment: unknown_codec
Metadata:
  filename        : fontastique.ttf
  mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
...etc...
```

The subtitles cannot find the font because it still appears as default font of the player, not the attached ones.

The [documentations](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) example says

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -attach DejaVuSans.ttf -metadata:s:2 mimetype=application/x-truetype-font out.mkv
```

but I have no idea what -metadata:s:2 means, I thought it tells it what stream to attach it to, but using `-metadata:s:2`, 2 being the subtitles stream, fails with

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Error number -22 occurred
```

How do I correctly copy or attach multiple fonts to a MKV container to be used by a .ass subtitle stream?

Answer (score 8):

First, you actually can copy fonts with `ffmpeg`. The `-map` option overrides some defaults and selects all streams from the input. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mkv -map 0 -c copy outfile.mkv
```

Also see the [FFmpeg Map documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more info.

For attaching fonts to an existing video, the `-metadata:s:2` option is indeed selecting stream 2, but if you look at your `mkvinfo` output you'll see that attachments are their own stream. They are not "attached" to the subtitle stream. So in the example in your question you would want `-metadata:s:3`. And additional attachments should use corresponding stream specifiers.